# How to see branch name next to Project directory in GoLand

Tags: goland

Is it possible to include the branch name next to the project in GoLand?

I see it by default with Pycharm:

[image]

In GoLand, I don't see it although the project come from a git repository:

[image]

Comment: Most likely, you've installed GitToolBox, which is a 3rd-party plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox). It is not a bundled functionality.

Comment: @s0xzwasd in fact, can you post your answer then i could accept your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin adds branch names to Project View so that you can install it in GoLand as PyCharm.